# Passing dynamic segment to child props using React routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Using the React router I'd like to be able to pass a dynamic segment of the url (e.g., `:id`) as a property to the child element, like so:

```js
<Routes>
    <Route path="/books/:id" element={<Book bookId={id} />} />
</Routes>
```

I know the following is possible:

```js
<Routes>
    <Route path="/books/:bookId" element={<Book />} />
</Routes>

...
export default function Book(props) {
    const { bookId } = useParams();
}
```

But then I would lose the flexibility of creating a book component with a specific `bookId` on-the-fly as the `bookId` now suddenly is tied to the params of the URL.

Any alternatives or suggestions are welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
you can use Context api 





 import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    
    const BookContext = createContext();
    
    function BookProvider(props) {
      const [bookId, setBookId] = useState(null);
      const [bookData, setBookData] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (bookId) {
          // fetch book data for the current bookId
          fetch(`/api/books/${bookId}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setBookData(data));
        }
      }, [bookId]);
    
      return (
        <BookContext.Provider value={{ bookId, setBookId, bookData }}>
          {props.children}
        </BookContext.Provider>
      );
    }
    
    function useBook() {
      const context = useContext(BookContext);
    
      if (!context) {
        throw new Error('useBook must be used within a BookProvider');
      }
    
      return context;
    }
    
    export { BookProvider, useBook };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion. It's a bit more elaborate than I expected the solution to be, but I'll digest this and definitely give this a try.